# C++ visual studio 2010 code ..error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, error-handling, build, compiler-errors

I am new to C++ and have a code that I need to fix. I am using C++ Visual Studio Express 2010. I am getting multiple errors and I am unsure of how to fix them Can someone help me fix this or show me how to do this correctly using Visual Studio express.![enter image description here][1]

I am trying to write a program that accepts as input the bill for a meal at a restaurant, calculates the tax, the tip, and the total and then displays the amounts.
Calculate the tax using a tax rate of 7% (use a value of 0.07).
Calculate the tip using 18% (use a value of 0.18).
Your program should do the following:
1. Prompt the user for the amount of the meal.
2. Calculate the tax.
3. Calculate the tip.
4. Calculate the total.
5. Display the following values:
The amount on the bill for the meal
The amount you should pay for tax
The amount for the tip
The total amount you should pay (meal + tax + tip).
HINT: Use the data type double for these variables.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double cost;
double tax;
double tip;
double total;

cout <<"please enter the cost of your meal: ";
cin >> cost;

tax = cost * 0.07;
tip = cost * 0.18;
total = cost + tax + tip;

cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
cout <<"\n\nThe cost of your meal is: " << cost << "\n";
cout <<"\n\nThe tax amount is: " << tax << "\n";
cout <<"\n\nThe tip amount is: " << tip << "\n";
cout <<"\n\nThe total cost is: " << total << "\n";


return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
return 0;
}
```

---

```
OUTPUT ERROR : 
1>------ Build started: Project: proj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
1> proj.cpp 
1>LINK : warning LNK4067: ambiguous entry point; selected 'mainCRTStartup' 
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========
```

Comment: Is this already set? [Link Error 1123](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb4a7699-0f3c-4701-9790-199787f1b359/vs-2010-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: One way is create an empty project and put your code in it, or try to move your code from main to _tmain